# Make this code run more synchronously

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
var getFile = document.getElementById("roll");
var init = getFile.files;
var rawResults = [];

if(init.length > 1){

    for(var i = 0, ii = init.length; i < ii; i++){

        Papa.parse(init[i], {
            delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
            newline: "",    // auto-detect
            header: true,
            dynamicTyping: false,
            preview: 0,
            encoding: "",
            worker: false,
            comments: false,
            step: undefined,
            complete: function(results, file) {
                rawResults.push(results.data);
            },
            error: undefined,
            download: false,
            skipEmptyLines: false,
            chunk: undefined,
            fastMode: undefined,
            beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
            withCredentials: undefined
        });
    }

    var flattening = _.flatten(rawResults);

    console.log(rawResults);
    console.log(rawResults.length);
}
```

When I try to run the `_.flatten` underscore function on the `rawResults` array, it comes up empty because the array isn't ready with the data due to the `getFile` function being asynchronous in nature.

The script takes an uploaded file, is then parsed via Papa Parse and the results then finally populated into the `rawResults` array.

I tried to create a callback function like this:

```
function firstfunction(callbackfxn){
    // Put the asynchronous getFile code here.
    callbackfxn();
};

function secondfunction(){
    firstfunction(function(){
        // Put the parsing code in here
    });
};
```

I tried other callback variations but had no luck in getting this to work like it's supposed to.

Comment: You could have a global variable called `successes` declared as 0 and another called `flattening `. Then each completion calls `complete: function(results, file) {
                rawResults.push(results.data);
                if(++ successes == init.length) {
                    flattening = _.flatten(rawResults);
                }
            },`

Comment: You could flatten on the last iteration of your complete callback. But then again there is still the possibility of an earlier http request finishing after a later http request.

Comment: If you use an input of type file you can can use the onchange event:


var getFile = document.querySelector("#roll")

getFile.onchange = function(event) {
   var fileUploaded = getFile.files[0];
   // Do stuff with uploaded file:
   console.log(getFile.files[0]);
}

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/be0qxyhs/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use some control flow library like bluebird or async.js?

Here's an example using [async#each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

## async.js

```
async.each(init, function(file, callback) {
  Papa.parse(init[i], {
    delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
    newline: "",    // auto-detect
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    encoding: "",
    worker: false,
    comments: false,
    step: undefined,
    complete: function(results, file) {
      rawResults.push(results.data);
      callback();
    },
    error: undefined,
    download: false,
    skipEmptyLines: false,
    chunk: undefined,
    fastMode: undefined,
    beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
    withCredentials: undefined
  });
}, function(error) {
  // do something if error
  var flattening = _.flatten(rawResults);

  console.log(rawResults);
  console.log(rawResults.length);
});
```

Loops through each element of the array applying the iterator function to the element. Once the complete event is triggered, it calls the callback function to tell the function that it's completed. The last argument to `async#each` is the error function. It's invoked once all elements have been processed. rawResults should be populated once this function is invoked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with Papa Parse. Basically just uploads the first file. I console logged inside the papa parse's complete key and there was nothing.

Comment: Basically, the callback function is never called and the problem with the rawResults array is the same as it was before.

Comment: Interesting. I would define an error property function. I think it's encountering an error and since you never define a error function, it doesn't call it.

Comment: When you say, there was nothing inside the complete function via console.log, do you mean it didn't print anything or the complete function was never called? If it was never called, that means it probably encountered an error somewhere.

Comment: When I remove the callback parameter inside the async.each, the callback function fires when called inside. When I use the callback function as a parameter, nothing gets called. It never gets called.

Comment: Perfect. I read more of the documentation and figured that the 3rd input/parameter of the async.each function is actually a results function, where I can actually do the flattening. I know you put that in your answer but I assumed that you made a mistake. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. Means a lot!

Comment: No problem. In the future, I would recommend also looking at bluebird as a control flow library. It's a Promise library with speed as one of its primary goals.